# Using dplyr rewrite a loop that shifts a value in a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

Here's simple loop in base R:

```
# prep
x <- sort(round(10 * rnorm(10)))
res.sd <- NULL
res.var <- NULL
res.mad <- NULL
#loop
for(i in -20:20){
 x[10] <- i
 res.sd <- c(res.sd, sd(x))
 res.var <- c(res.var, var(x))
 res.mad <- c(res.mad, mad(x))
}
```

I would like to rewrite this in dplyr

Comment: `dplyr` is usually used for dataframes. Do you mean just using a non-loop-based approach to your problem?

Comment: Maybe map/apply functions are more suitable for this case.

Comment: @ekoam: Yes. Also I agree: the question could have been better formulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a combination of purrr and tibble.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0)

x <- sort(round(10 * rnorm(10)))

map_dfr(-20:20, ~ tibble(
  res.sd = sd(c(x[-10], .)),
  res.var = var(c(x[-10], .)),
  res.mad = mad(c(x[-10], .))
))
#> # A tibble: 41 × 3
#>    res.sd res.var res.mad
#>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1   11.7    138.    15.6
#>  2   11.6    134.    15.6
#>  3   11.4    130.    15.6
#>  4   11.2    126.    15.6
#>  5   11.1    122.    15.6
#>  6   10.9    119.    15.6
#>  7   10.8    116.    14.8
#>  8   10.6    113.    14.1
#>  9   10.5    110.    13.3
#> 10   10.4    108.    12.6
#> # … with 31 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding your code correctly, it does the following:

1. Generate 10 random numbers stored in `x`.
2. In a loop that iterates over `-20:20`, replace the 10th value of `x` with the iterated value.
3. Calculate the SD, variance, and median absolute deviation of the modified vector, and store these calculations.

As ekoam points out, this type of operation is ill-suited to dplyr's intended purpose. That said, the ability to store list-columns makes this possible (albeit inefficient, since it requires storing multiple copies of the `x` vector). The following will produce equivalent results to your code, if you add `set.seed(0)` before the first line to control randomization.

```
set.seed(0)
df <- tibble(
  x = list(sort(round(10 * rnorm(10)))),
  y = -20:20
) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    res.sd = sd(c(x[-10], y)),
    res.var = var(c(x[-10], y)),
    res.mad = mad(c(x[-10], y))
  )

# A tibble: 41 × 5
# Rowwise: 
   x              y res.sd res.var res.mad
   <list>     <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 <dbl [10]>   -20   11.7    138.    15.6
 2 <dbl [10]>   -19   11.6    134.    15.6
 3 <dbl [10]>   -18   11.4    130.    15.6
 4 <dbl [10]>   -17   11.2    126.    15.6
 5 <dbl [10]>   -16   11.1    122.    15.6
 6 <dbl [10]>   -15   10.9    119.    15.6
 7 <dbl [10]>   -14   10.8    116.    14.8
 8 <dbl [10]>   -13   10.6    113.    14.1
 9 <dbl [10]>   -12   10.5    110.    13.3
10 <dbl [10]>   -11   10.4    108.    12.6
```

Alternately, we could get a little clever with the `lapply` and `sapply`, and then store the result in a tibble. Note that there is almost no repeated code here:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- sort(round(10 * rnorm(10)))
y <- -20:20
lapply(list(sd = sd, var = var, mad = mad), function(func) {
  
  sapply(y, function(j) {
    func(c(x[-10], j))
  }) 
}) %>% 
  as_tibble()

# A tibble: 41 × 3
      sd   var   mad
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  11.7  138.  15.6
 2  11.6  134.  15.6
 3  11.4  130.  15.6
 4  11.2  126.  15.6
 5  11.1  122.  15.6
 6  10.9  119.  15.6
 7  10.8  116.  14.8
 8  10.6  113.  14.1
 9  10.5  110.  13.3
10  10.4  108.  12.6
# … with 31 more rows
```